# Get name of folder in same directory as bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can i get the name of this folder from within myScript.bat?

Dir->
    myScript.bat
    needThisFolderName

Want it when I run myScript.bat
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If there is multiple folders how are we supposed to determine which one to grab?

Comment: Theres only one folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple FOR /D command then.

```
FOR /D %%G IN (*) DO SET FOLDER=%%G
```